# RxJava - return after some method is completed

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I am quite new to RxJava and I am tryign to implement and OAuth2 flow with refresh tokens in my Android/Kotlin app.

I got a bit stuck with refreshing my access tokens inside an interceptor (I append access token for each API request inside an `OAuthAuthenticator`). The problem is that I would like to wait with populating the request until the token request is completed.

Could someone hint me how to achieve this?

This is my authenticator class:

```
class OAuthAuthenticator(
        private val authStateManager: AuthStateManager,
        private val authRepository: AuthRepository): Authenticator {

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response?): Request? {

        // handle invalid token
        if (response != null && response.code() == 401) {
            println("Invalid access token")

            authRepository.refreshToken()
                    .subscribe { _ ->
                        println("Token refreshed")
                    }
        }

        // this should happen after the token request is completed since it would fail again otherwise
        return response?.request()!!
                .newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authStateManager.current.accessToken)
                .build()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making an asyncronous call inside a synchronous method. That won't work. You will have to put your code that you want to be executed after token request has been completed inside the rx chain.

```
class OAuthAuthenticator(
        private val authStateManager: AuthStateManager,
        private val authRepository: AuthRepository) : Authenticator {

        override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response?): Single<Request> {
            // handle invalid token
            if (response != null && response.code() == 401) {
                return Single.error(InvalidAccessTokenException("Invalid access token"))
            }

            return Single.fromCallable { authRepository.refreshAccessToken() }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map {
                    return@map response?.request()!!
                        .newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " +
                                authStateManager.current.accessToken)
                        .build()
                }
        }
    }
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
val authenticator = OAuthAuthenticator(authStateManager, authRepository)
val disposable = authenticator.authenticate(route, response)
            .subscribe({ _ ->
                println("Token refreshed")
            }, { error ->
                if (error is InvalidAccessTokenException) {
                    println("Invalid access token")
                } else {
                    println("Could not refresh token. Signing out...")
                    authStateManager.signOut()
                }
            })
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwers. Unfortunately, the OkHttp authenticator's itnerface dictates that this method must return `Result`, not `Single<Result>` so this won't work. This authenticator is registered in OkHttp3 client and used internally.

Comment: Oh, I see. In this case you probably don't even need to use rxjava inside  the authenticate method since it should be executed on the background thread by default.

Comment: But how do I make it wait until the token request if finished? The authenticator will try to perform multiple requests in the row with the old token if I do not make it synchronous somehow..

Comment: What does authRepository.refreshAccessToken() return?

Comment: It does not return anything. It performs some request (we are using AppAuth framework) and updates its auth state once it's finished

Comment: Why not refresh your token before you make the network call? Then you can just get it  from authRepository inside authenticate method.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear. I only get to know that my token is invalid when making a request so this approach would not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`blockingGet()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#blockingGet--) to make the `Single` synchronous. But that's not advised. But since you create the `Single` locally with

```
Single.fromCallable { authRepository.refreshAccessToken() }
```

you could just call the appropriate method directly without wrapping it with *Rx*.

```
if (response != null && response.code() == 401) {
    println("Invalid access token")
    try {
        authRepository.refreshAccessToken()
        println("Token refreshed")
    } catch(error: Throwable) {
        println("Could not refresh token. Signing out...")
        authStateManager.signOut()
        return null
    }
}
```